# Doing calculation on SQL count() value

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish to calulate the item in the warehouse and calculate the free space in the warehouse, then output to a table with column of Inshelf and free and I come up with something like these.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Inshelf, free=10-Inshelf
  FROM stock.stockproduct 
 WHERE StockNum = 1
   AND checkOutData is NULL;
```

Appearly it won't work, are there having any simple solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: Can you include some data for testing, table structure and specify on wich RDBMS are you working, MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle.

Comment: and the schema is every simple. should be two column with Inshelf and free. and one row of result

Comment: The schema of your source table `stock.stockproduct`

Comment: OIC, [productID][productName][stocklocation]

Comment: `WHERE StockNum = 1 AND checkOutData is NULL` - you have no checkOutData or StockNum column in the 'schema' you just provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't work - results of aggregate functions (e.g. `count()`) are not available until after all of the records have been considered. You need to this with a subquery, doing the count in the subquery, the your subtraction in the outer one. Without knowing your DB schema, this is at best a guess, but...

```
SELECT InShelf, free - InShelf
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) AS Inshelf, free
    FROM stockproduct
    WHERE StockNum = 1 AND checkOutData IS NULL
    GROUP BY somefield
) AS a
```

Comment: Unknow columne  'free' in field list

Comment: @user1660416: Look at what you wrote in your question and what Marc wrote in his answer, and then use your head to figure out what `free` is in the field list and fix it. You really should learn to try to actually read and understand things, not just copy and paste them. Marc, +1. Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Work !!

```
SELECT InShelf, 10 - InShelf
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) AS Inshelf, count(*) AS free
    FROM stock.stockproduct
    WHERE StockNum = 1 AND checkOutData IS NULL

) AS a;
```

Thank all, and sry for being stupid =.='